# How to reference an existing model instance while creating other model instance?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

*Newbie in sequelize.js*

I have two models: `User` and `Organization` and I am trying to simulate *A user can be admin of one organization, organization can have only one admin* (one-to-one) association using `belongsTo()`.

Here is how models are defined:

```
const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
        firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
        lastName: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    { underscored: true }
);

const Organization = sequelize.define(
    "Organization",
    {
        name: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    { underscored: true }
);

Organization.belongsTo(User, {
    as: "admin",
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Here is what I want to do in sequence:

1. Create a User.
2. Create an Organization and then set the created User as the admin.

The issue:

> It does not let me specify an already existing user as admin.

Here is what I tried: (By looking at documentation and other examples)
1.

```
// step 1
await User.create({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
});

// step 2
const adminToSet = await User.findOne({ where: { firstName: "John" } });
await Organization.create(
    {
        name: "my-awesome-organization",
        User: adminToSet
    },
    {
        include: [{ model: User, as: "admin" }]
    }
);
```

It gives me error saying `'Organization.admin_id cannot be null'`

2.

```
// step 1
await User.create({
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
});

// step 2
const adminToSet = await User.findOne({ where: { firstName: "John" } });
const org = Organization.build({
    name: "my-awesome-organization"
});
org.setAdmin(adminToSet);
```

It gives me error saying `id = id || results && results[0][this.getInsertIdField()];` (which seems to be of the `mssql` -> the dialect I am using)

Please help!

Here is the complete code snippet:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const connectionOptions = {
    username: "sa",
    password: "Test@123",
    dialect: "mssql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1433,
    operatorsAliases: false,
    benchmark: true,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    // Dialect specific options. These will be passed to the db driver
    dialectOptions: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionOptions);

const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
        firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
        lastName: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    { underscored: true }
);

const Organization = sequelize.define(
    "Organization",
    {
        name: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    { underscored: true }
);

Organization.belongsTo(User, {
    as: "admin",
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
    }
});

const createUserAndOrganization = async () => {
    // step 1
    await User.create({
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
    });

    // step 2
    const adminToSet = await User.findOne({ where: { firstName: "John" } });
    const org = Organization.build({
        name: "my-awesome-organization"
    });
    org.setAdmin(adminToSet);
};

const authenticated = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
        await createUserAndOrganization();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(authenticated)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(`[${err.name}]`, `[${err.original.code}]`, `${err.original.message}`);
    });
```